# Trying to send an array to a method that would split each element using String.split()

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have created an array that takes each line of a txt file and stores it in each index. Now, I need to split each of them using String.split(). I have a method that would correctly do the split operation, but I need to create a method that will store each element of my array in a string to pass it through to that method. The fact that each element of the array is being stored from an external txt file makes it even trickier. Any suggestions as to how to do this? Here is all of my code:

```
//store each line into an array
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class InfixToPostfix {
private ObjectStack operator;


public InfixToPostfix() {
    operator = new ObjectStack();
}   

/**
 * method takes each expression from infix.txt and stores them in a string array
 * @param none
 * @return none
 */
public String getInfix() {

//declare new filestream    
FileInputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream("infix.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//declare a reader
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));


//declare string array to store elements in
String[] list = new String[10];

try {
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            try {
                list[i] = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    while (br.readLine() != null);
}

catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return (Arrays.toString(list));
}

//and the method that would perform the split
public static void parseArray(String entries) {
    String delims = "[ ]+";
    String[] tokens = entries.split(delims);
}
```

here is the txt file: 8 + 4 * 2 - 6

7 * 2 - 4 * 3 + 2 * 5

2 * 3 * 4 - 8 + 9 / 3 / 3

5 + 7 * 4 - 6

4 * ( 3 + 2 * 4 ) - 7

( 5 + 7 ) / ( 9 - 5 )

3 * ( 5 * ( 5 - 2 ) ) - 9

( ( 5 * ( 4 + 2 ) - ( 8 + 8 ) / 2 ) - 9 ) ^ 3

( ( 5 + 5 * ( 6 - 2 ) + 4 ^ 2 ) * 8 )

( ( ( 3 ^ 4 ) ) )

Comment: OK you described what you want to achieve (more or less) but you didn't describe what problem you are having with your code. Could you post some example of input, expected output/result and actual output/result/problem you are facing while implementing your method?

Comment: To clarify, you wish to split the contents of the file by a certain string pattern?

Comment: @Pshemo The problem isn't with the data being stored from the txt file because I have used a print method to make sure it was all correctly stored in the array. The problem I have is somehow splitting each element of the array so that I can send it to another method that allows me to tamper with the operands and operators in each line by using a stack to convert them to postfix notation. I'm sorry if I'm not being clear, it's hard for me to put this all to words.

Comment: @Celeo I have stored the contents of the file into each element of an array that contains 10 indexes. I wish to split each of those elements from that array by the certain pattern (split each time there is a space)

Comment: Loop through the array and perform the `split()` call on the elements, then.

Comment: @Celeo I'm a pretty beginner programmer so I'm having trouble making sense of what you're saying. Are you saying I need to create a loop in the method that creates the array that sends each element of the array to the method that performs the split? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Not that it solves your main problem but your `do {...} while (br.readLine() != null);` will actually skip line you read inside condition because you are not storing it anywhere. Maybe consider doing something more like `String line =null; while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){ doYourStuffWithLine;}`.

Comment: @Pshemo I actually had that word for word, but it was causing everything to jumble up out of order. It was weird. I will look into that after I can get the whole program to do what it's supposed to. The do/while statement is just temporary. Good eye though. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post example of input and expected output/result with little explanation ow why such result should be expected? I have few ideas of how to improve your code but I am not sure which one to describe and I don't want to write entire article about each of improvements I though of because most of them will probably be not needed or maybe you will be not allowed to use them (BTW are there any limitations of datatypes you can use in your code?).

Comment: @Pshemo this is the txt file that I have stored into the array: [8 + 4 * 2 - 6
7 * 2 - 4 * 3 + 2 * 5
2 * 3 * 4 - 8 + 9 / 3 / 3
5 + 7 * 4 - 6
4 * ( 3 + 2 * 4 ) - 7
( 5 + 7 ) / ( 9 - 5 )
3 * ( 5 * ( 5 - 2 ) ) - 9
( ( 5 * ( 4 + 2 ) - ( 8 + 8 ) / 2 ) - 9 ) ^ 3
( ( 5 + 5 * ( 6 - 2 ) + 4 ^ 2 ) * 8 )
( ( ( 3 ^ 4 ) ) )]

I need to use a stack that we created in my class to convert this to postfix notation. Now, to send this stuff into a stack, I first put it into an array line-by-line. Now I want to split the array elements so that I can easily pop and push each operator and operand.

Comment: @amirbad I don't see any line separators here. Consider [[edit]]ting your question to add this information there with proper formatting.

Comment: @Pshemo It's now in the question. Sorry. Also, I edited my last comment. It says:  I need to use a stack that we created in my class to convert this to postfix notation. Now, to send this stuff into a stack, I first put it into an array line-by-line. Now I want to split the array elements so that I can easily pop and push each operator and operand.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Lists (instead of arrays)?

Comment: @Pshemo I can use anything to store the lines, I just need to use the stack class to convert it. Is it possible to split lists? How would I store each line of this txt file into a list, and then send each line to the splitter method? lastly, would the splitter method assign a string value to each line so that I could send it into the stack class I have? Sorry for all the questions...

Comment: It seems that your entire `getInfix()` method can be replaced with `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("infix.txt"))` which will return `List<String>` which will store each line in each List element. Now you can just iterate over this lines like `for(String line : returnedListWithLines){doAnythingWithLine}`

Comment: Then it seems that you can just split each line on space with `line.split(" ")`, but I am not entirely sure how you want to put elements from each line into stack. Maybe this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm will help a little.

Comment: @Pshemo So I would say:
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("infix.txt");
Then could you explain that second part? the "for(String line : returnedListWithLines){doAnythingWithLine}" --- I don't understand. Would I send it to the splitter method in the loop?

Comment: @Pshemo hmmm, I see. Thank you for helping. This does make it easier, but I'll have to see how to have the string splitter send each line to the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it too work. I know it's a few days later, but I forgot to post it. Here it is:

```
/**
 * @author Amir
 * Converts from infix to postfix
 */

import java.io.*;

public class InfixToPostfix {
    private ObjectStack realStack;
    private EvalPostFix eval;
    //private SuperOutput so;
    private PrintWriter pw;

/**
 * constructor
 * @param pw 
 */ 
public InfixToPostfix(PrintWriter pw) {
    realStack = new ObjectStack();
    //eval = new EvalPostFix(); 
    this.pw = pw;   
    }

/**
 * method takes each expression from infix.txt and stores them in a string array
 * @param none
 * @return none
 */
public void getInfix() {

//declare new filestream    
FileInputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream("infix.txt");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//declare a reader
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

//declare string array to store elements in
String[] list = new String[10];

try {
    do {
        for (int n = 0; n < list.length; n++){
            try {
                list[n] = br.readLine();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
         for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            splitArray(list[i]);
         }
    }
    while (br.readLine() != null);
}

catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    //splitArray(Arrays.toString(list));
}

/**
 * Method that splits each line by the spaces
 * @param entries
 */
public void splitArray(String entries) {

    String delims = "[ ]+";
    String[] tokens = entries.split(delims);
//      for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
//          System.out.println(tokens[i]);
    convertToPostfix(tokens);
}

/**
 * method that converts from infix to postfix
 * @param tokens
 */
public void convertToPostfix(String[] tokens) {
    StringBuffer br = new StringBuffer();

    for (int n = 0; n < tokens.length; n++) {
        char element = tokens[n].charAt(0);
        if (element <= '9' && element >= '0') {
            br.append(element);
        }
        else if (element == '^' || element == '/' || element == '*' || element == '+' || element == '-' || element == '(') {
            while (!realStack.isEmpty() && (priorityVal(element) <= priorityVal((Character) realStack.top())) && (element !='('))
                br.append(realStack.pop());
            realStack.push(element);

        }
        else if (element == ')') {
            while ((!(realStack.top().equals('('))))
                br.append(realStack.pop());
            realStack.pop();

        }
    }
    while (!realStack.isEmpty())
        br.append(realStack.pop());


    System.out.println(br.toString());
    pw.println(br.toString());

    //eval.evaluate(br.toString());

}

/**
 * method that assigns priority value to each operator
 * @param operator
 * @return priority value
 */
private int priorityVal(char operator) {
    switch (operator) {
    case '^': return 3;
    case '/': 
    case '*': return 2;
    case '+': 
    case '-': return 1;
    default : return 0;
    }
}   

}
```

Also, here is the ObjectStack class that we made in class in case anyone was actually wondering what the stack we created looks like and what it is that I'm implementing in this code. Idk, may be useful to someone:

```
public class ObjectStack {
    private Object[] item;
    private int top;

public ObjectStack() {
    item = new Object[1];
    top = -1;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return top == -1;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return top == item.length-1;
}

public void clear() {
    item = new Object[1];
    top = -1;
}

public void push(Object o) {
    if (isFull())
        resize(2 * item.length);
    item[++top] = o;
}

public void resize(int size) {
    Object[] temp = new Object[size];
    for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
        temp[i] = item[i];
    item = temp;
}

public Object pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Stack Underflow");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Object temp = item[top];
    item[top--] = null;
    if (top == item.length/4)
        resize(item.length/2);
    return temp;
}

public Object top() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Stack Underflow");
        System.exit(1);
    }    
    return item[top];
}
}
```

And here is the driver:

```
/**
* @author Amir
* Driver class
*/

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class Driver {

/**
 * main static method
 * @param args
 */
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException  {  
    //SuperOutput so = new SuperOutput("csis.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter ("csis.txt"));
    InfixToPostfix infixToPostfix = new InfixToPostfix(pw);

    System.out.println("Hello and welcome to Amir's magical infix-to-postfix converter!");
    pw.println("Hello and welcome to Amir's magical infix-to-postfix converter!");
    System.out.println("Please wait while I fetch 'infix.txt'...");
    pw.println("Please wait while I fetch 'infix.txt'...");

    try {
        System.out.println("The original txt file contains as follows: " + Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("infix.txt")));
        pw.println("The original txt file contains as follows: " + Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("infix.txt")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //infixToPostfix.getInfix();
    infixToPostfix.getInfix();
    pw.close();


}
}
```